# Does Pydev provide dynamic substitution variables, e.g. to identify a project's interpreter?

Tags: eclipse, pydev

Does Pydev provide dynamic substitution variables, specifically one that could be used to identify the Python interpreter used in a Pydev project?

I would like to use the Eclipse plugin [EasyShell](https://github.com/anb0s/EasyShell) to define a command that has to know whether it is executed in the context of a Python 2 or Python 3 project. EasyShell commands can parameterized with Eclipse substitutition variables. Of course, other suggestions how to achieve my goal are welcome.

Edit: To be a little more specific, in Eclipse I have defined an EasyShell command with the substitution variables `${easyshell:container_loc}` and `${easyshell:project_name}` as parameters. The command executes a bash script that uses the variable values to locate the source folder of the Python project and eventually calls pylint. I would like to add a parameter to the command that hints at the Python interpreter specified in Pydev for the project. Hopefully, I could then find out whether its a Python 2 or Python 3 project and call the version of pylint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's such a variable from PyDev to be used.

To give more suggestions I'd need more info on what exactly are you trying to achieve...

Comment: I have edited my original question to provide some more information

Comment: Why not just use the PyLint integration that is builtin into PyDev? (http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_pylint.html -- newer version have an option to use PyLint from the interpreter you have for the project by default)

Comment: I'm using the PyLint integration. But for an overview of the state of a project and for fixing (or ignoring) different kinds of Pylint message categories I find the textual output more helpful.

Comment: Well, given that there's no such variable, my suggestion is either providing a pull request to add such variable into PyDev (so you could use it there) or having your script parse `.pydevproject` to gather that information.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the skills to provide a pull request for PyDev. But parsing `.pydevproject` is a good suggestion. Looking a some PyDev projects, I have found values of `python 2.7` and `python 3.0` for `PYTHON_PROJECT_VERSION`. Can I use that parameter or do I have to follow the value of `PYTHON_PROJECT_INTERPRETER`?

Comment: That's up to you (if in your case you can derive the location from the version it'd be fine to use `PYTHON_PROJECT_VERSION`).